# Does generator matrix of a code $C$ must have linearly independent rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

> Def: A generator matrix $G$ with entries in $\mathbb{F}_q$ generates code $C$, and each rows of $G$ is basis of $C$.

---

Does generator matrix of a code $C$ must have linearly independent rows?

---

For example, let $G_{ex}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{F}_3$, I am not sure this $G$ can be a valid generator matrix or not. Most generator matrix in the textbook are in systematic form,, but if a $G$ not in systematic form, we can use row reduction to make $G$ in systematic form. At this point, I can $rref(G_{ex})$ into systematic form. 
I think this is a true statement. If my explanation isn't correct, can someone explain to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator matrix doesn't *have* to have linearly independent rows, but
linear independence of rows is generally a good property to have. If the rows are linearly *dependent*, then two or more different data vectors will be mapped onto the same code vector, and thus, *even in the absence of
any channel errors*, the decoder will not be able to determine which data vector was transmitted.

In the example that you have constructed, data vectors $00, 11, 22$ all
are mapped onto the same code vector $000$.

Comment: But we still can use row reduction to reduce $G$ into a systematic form, this would give the same code?

Comment: @Simple: Yes, you can do row reduction. If you do that to your $2\times3$ matrix the second row becomes all zeros. The code is 1-dimensional.